# Use DataProvider in test scenario

Tags: testng, dataprovider, chain

If I have multiple @Test methods which must be in a chain and I want to use DataProvider to pass more data for the whole test scenario what is the proper way of doing that.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

   private int type = -1;

   @DataProvider
   public Object[][] mock() {
      return new Object[][] { { 1, "Hello" }, { 2, "World" } };
   }

   @Test(groups = { "A" }, priority = 0, dataProvider = "mock")
   public void testOne(int i, String name) {
      System.out.println("TestClass.testOne()");
      switch (i) {
      case 1:
         type = 1;
         Assert.assertEquals(name, "Hello");
         break;
      case 2:
         type = 2;
         Assert.assertEquals(name, "World");
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }
   }

   @Test(groups = { "A" }, priority = 1)
   public void testTwo() {
      Assert.assertEquals(type != -1, true);
      System.out.println("TestClass.testTwo()");
   }
}
```

Every time when testOne is invoked with the mocked data after it testTwo must be invoked also:
Resutlt -> 
TestClass.testOne()
TestClass.testOne()
TestClass.testTwo()

Expected result ->
TestClass.testOne()
TestClass.testTwo()
TestClass.testOne()
TestClass.testTwo()

This is my suite xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" group-by-instances="true">
  <test name="Test" verbose="3" group-by-instances="true" >
    <classes>

      <class name="demo.test.src.TestClass">

      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a Factory coupled with a data provider for getting this done.

Here's a sample of how it can look like :

```
public class TestClass {

    private int type = - 1;
    private String name;

    @Factory (dataProvider = "mock")
    public TestClass(int type, String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] mock() {
        return new Object[][] {{1, "Hello"}, {2, "World"}};
    }

    @Test (groups = {"A"})
    public void testOne() {
        System.out.println("TestClass.testOne()");
        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                type = 1;
                Assert.assertEquals(name, "Hello");
                break;
            case 2:
                type = 2;
                Assert.assertEquals(name, "World");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Test (groups = {"A"}, dependsOnMethods = "testOne")
    public void testTwo() {
        Assert.assertEquals(type != - 1, true);
        System.out.println("TestClass.testTwo()");
    }
}
```

You then make use of a TestNG suite xml file that leverages `group-by-instances` attribute (a sample is shown below)

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="factory-suite"  verbose="2" group-by-instances="true" >
    <test name="factory-test">
        <classes>
            <class name="org.rationale.emotions.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: ok but the output is 
TestClass.testOne()
TestClass.testOne()
TestClass.testTwo()
TestClass.testTwo()

This is not the expected one.

Comment: @JordanBorisov add a "group-by-instances" = true to your suite xml file and after that you will see methods for every instance being run together.

Comment: OK now I have this output (which is the same) :
===== Invoked methods
    TestClass.testOne()[pri:0, instance:demo.test.src.TestClass@28feb3fa] 687780858
    TestClass.testOne()[pri:0, instance:demo.test.src.TestClass@68be2bc2] 1757293506
    TestClass.testTwo()[pri:1, instance:demo.test.src.TestClass@28feb3fa] 687780858
    TestClass.testTwo()[pri:1, instance:demo.test.src.TestClass@68be2bc2] 1757293506
=====

Comment: @JordanBorisov - If my answer helped you out, can you please help accept my answer ?

Comment: No actually it does not help me

Comment: @JordanBorisov - Can you please help me understand what is missing ?

Comment: I want the execution to be (Method1 Method2) (Method1 Method2)

Comment: @JordanBorisov - Group-by-instances=true is going to do exactly that. Can you share your suite xml file that you are using ?

Comment: @JordanBorisov - I think for your case to work properly viz., the method executions need to follow an order, you would have to resort to using depends-on-methods instead of using priority. You can take a look at this gist I created : https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/cc2c473a0a117d821b06c9ea793fb361